# Como depurar programas em C pelo Prompt de Comando?

Tags: c, windows, debug, cmd

Estou precisando depurar um algoritmo em linguagem C mas a máquina que estou utilizando não tem o Code::Blocks. Qual o caminho para que eu possa depurar no Prompt de Comando do Windows ?

Answer (score 3):

Para depurar pelo Comand Promp apenas existem duas opções.Ou usa um debugger sem interface gráfica como é o caso do GDB, ou utiliza output de texto.

Isto é através de `printf` ou até `fprintf` pode "printar" o valor das variáveis em causa, ou se quiser saber se chega a entrar numa condição pode colocar dentro dela de maneira a ter a certeza.

Não é a melhor, mas quando não se tem recursos quase tudo serve.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado ajudou bastante

Answer (score 2):

Um ótimo programa para debug de códigos em C é o gdb, e para conseguir dar o debug no código, é preciso compila-lo com o parametro -g, que compila o código e cria um arquivo binário para debug.
Ao abrir o arquivo no gdb você usa esses comandos:

```
b método/linha - coloca um breakpoint na linha ou no método desejado
r              - inicia o debug
n              - faz o breakpoint ir para a proxima linha
c              - executa até o proximo breakpoint
q              - sai do gdb
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante cara !